# How to I modify the code to apply it for three drop-downs? (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a jquery code which changes according to the previously selected value of drop-down.
I use it when I have two drop-downs and it works flawlessly.

Now the problem is that I am working with 3 drop-downs and I am unable to modify the code according to 3 drop-downs (reason my being new to jquery).

**This is the code:**

**Jquery:**

```
jQuery(function(){
var $cat = $('select[name=coursename]'),
    $items = $('select[name=semno]');

    $cat.change(function(){
    var $this = $(this).find(':selected'),
        rel = $this.attr('rel'),
        $set = $items.find('option.' + rel);

    if ($set.size() < 0) {
        $items.hide();
        return;
    }

    $items.show().find('option').hide();

    $set.show().first().prop('selected', true);});});
```

I used two drop-downs namely, *coursename* and *semno*, with this code and it works perfectly fine.

Now I want to add another dropdown, *subnm* which comes after *semno*.
So what I exactly want is that when a person makes a particular selection in *coursename* the relevant items should appear in *semno* and among those relevant items, when a value is selected, the items are listed on *subnm* accordingly.

I have used rel and class in the option element.

**HTML Code**

```
Course: 
<select name="coursename" id="coursename">
<option value="xyz" rel="xyz">XYZ</option>
<option value="abc" rel="abc">ABC</option>
</select>

Semester: 
<select name="semno" id="sem">
<option value="one" class="xyz">I</option>
<option value="two" class="xyz">II</option>
<option value="three" class="abc">III</option>
</select>

Subject: 
<select name="subnm" id="subnm">
<option value="p">p</option>
<option value="q">q</option>
<option value="r">r</option>
</select>
```

I guess I will need a rel option on the *semno* drop-down and then class on the *subnm* drop-down in accordance to the *semno* rel.

Forgive me if I am not 100% comprehensible. I am new to this site and I really need help.

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want. I have used the same function for change event for the second `select` menu.

```
$items.change(function(){
  var $this = $(this).find(':selected'),
  rel = $this.attr('rel'),
  $set = $third.find('option.' + rel);

  if ($set.size() < 0) {
     $third.hide();
     return;
  }
  $third.show().find('option').hide();
  $set.show().first().prop('selected', true);
});
```

Also I have triggered the change event for second `select` in `change` event handler of first `select`.

```
$items.trigger("change");
```

Please refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/og40zghd/)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I copy-pasted the exact code in my js file but It isn't reflected any changes on the select element. Is it because I have the two-level drop-down's jquery in the same js file?

Comment: Can you please share the final code of your js file? is it same as that in fiddle?

Comment: Hi @Developer107 I am really sorry for the later reply, was stuck up with exams. I have modified it and it refuses to work :( Please check the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/mgokdysx/

Comment: Did you check it, @Developer107 ?

Comment: Yes you didn't include jquery in fiddle. I updated it - https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/mgokdysx/2/

Comment: Ya actually I had added it and it worked. Thanks a lot for your help. @Developer107